# Oracle Query with Unknown WHERE clause

Tags: database, oracle, performance, query-optimization

We have a table with 100 columns. The end user is allowed to write any query trying to search on practically any column.

Essentially, they construct the query dynamically from a screen and the WHERE condition can have any number or combination of columns.

Example

```
 select * from my_tab where col1=x
 select * from my_tab where col1=x and col2=y and ....col10 =q
 select * from my_tab where col10=a and col20=4 and col30=r
```

While this is possible syntactically, the biggest problem is performance because you cannot have all possible combination of indexes.

I know this seems to be "query from hell" but still :

What can be other approaches ( both - technical and non-technical ) to this problem ?

Comment: You seem to think that it is necessary to index any possible column.  This is not so.  Indexes are not silver bullets that magically eliminate performance issues.  If an index is not selective enough, it will be ignored.  And with multiple columns, developing an access plan becomes far more complex. And of course indexes become a drag on performance for DML, because they have to be maintained as well as the underlying table.  The best approach is to address _real_, _demonstrated_ performance issues.

Comment: Do you keep track of the queries your users run? Can you analyze the queries, to see, for example, if a very large fraction of them always include a filter on a small number of columns (such as "by date" or "by customer id", etc.)? Those are the columns that you should index - especially if the filters are generally very selective (most users select only "last week" out of five years of data, or only one customer at a time out of your 30,000 customers, etc.)

Comment: Hi, your reach the limit of classic RDBMS. you need a search engine: try other database like Elasticsearch  or crateDB